# I can't figure out a proper SVN solution for Atom

Tags: svn, plugins, package, repository, atom-editor

I've been working with git a lot but the present work environment is using SVN!

They are using eclipse which I don't feel comfortable with also I may need to use some great packages from Atom.

However, I tried this plugin: https://github.com/andischerer/atom-svn

But! After the installation, I don't have a clue what to do.

1. How to connect to the repository with my authentication details
2. How do you commit or use the SVN commands?

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you're talking about can't do things like commit. All it does is color the gutter to indicate lines that have been modified, added, or deleted.

There are other Atom packages which can do those things, but they all assume something about a tool you're using.

- [rabbitvcs-svn](https://atom.io/packages/rabbitvcs-svn) - assumes you use RabbitVCS (Linux)
- [tortoise-svn](https://atom.io/packages/tortoise-svn) - assumes TortoiseSVN on (Windows)

Comment: Thank you, now I understand properly! However, I will have to use the tortoise-svn. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for "svn" packages and you should find what you are looking for.  While it would be nice to have SVN features as part of the application like Git and Github have been integrated, that hasn't been done yet.